# nullGrob error on plotting in ggplot2 / metR

Tags: r, ggplot2, metr

I am plotting (using `ggplot2`) a series of 3D data as a 2D surface plot with a colour scale for the vertical axis. I'm also plotting contours and contour labels (using `metR`).

I've come across some data that makes the plot fail with the error `Error in nullGrob() : could not find function "nullGrob"`.

I believe the error is due to an interaction between `geom_raster` and `geom_text_contour`; when trying all combinations of the different `geom`'s, only those that contain both `geom_raster` and `geom_text_contour` fail.

Additionally, if I remove the restriction of `expand=expansion(mult = 0, add = 0)`, the error doesn't occur.

What is this error, and how can I make it go away?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(metR)
library(readr)

df <- read_tsv("https://pastebin.com/raw/dJ7gM496")

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, z = z, fill = z)) + 
  geom_raster(interpolate=TRUE) +
  geom_contour2(color = "black", alpha=0.5) +
  geom_text_contour(aes(z = z)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=expansion(mult = 0, add = 0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand=expansion(mult = 0, add = 0))
```

sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] readr_1.3.1   metR_0.6.0    ggplot2_3.3.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.4        pillar_1.4.3      compiler_3.6.3    plyr_1.8.6        tools_3.6.3       digest_0.6.25     lubridate_1.7.4  
 [8] memoise_1.1.0     lifecycle_0.2.0   tibble_3.0.0      gtable_0.3.0      checkmate_2.0.0   pkgconfig_2.0.3   rlang_0.4.5      
[15] cli_2.0.2         rstudioapi_0.11   curl_4.3          withr_2.1.2       dplyr_0.8.5       stringr_1.4.0     vctrs_0.2.4      
[22] hms_0.5.3         grid_3.6.3        tidyselect_1.0.0  glue_1.3.2        data.table_1.12.8 R6_2.4.1          fansi_0.4.1      
[29] purrr_0.3.3       farver_2.0.3      magrittr_1.5      backports_1.1.5   scales_1.1.0      ellipsis_0.3.0    assertthat_0.2.1 
[36] colorspace_1.4-1  labeling_0.3      stringi_1.4.6     munsell_0.5.0     crayon_1.3.4
```

Comment: also maybe explicitly attaching the `grid` package helps

Comment: @Tjebo the data isn't random, and I've tried subsetting it, and the error went away.

Comment: @Tjebo : attaching the `grid` package worked. As it was working yesterday morning, I can only assume the package updates I did in the afternoon either broke something, or fixed an error I was implicitly relying on.

Comment: OK. I was using the multiplot function, which calls `grid` explicitly. After reloading my workspace and fixing some aesthetics with the graphs, I tried calling the plotting functions before I loaded multiplot. Therefore, I didn't have `grid` loaded.

Comment: glad it helped. I saw you included the link into the code now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As given by @Tjebo, explicitly attaching the `grid` package solved the problem; `nullGrob()` is a [function in that package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/grid/versions/3.6.2/topics/grid.null).

The issue was in my use of the [multiplot function](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/). The function includes an explicit call to `grid`. When I was playing with some of my plots and reloading workspaces, I ended up playing with my plot before loading multiplot, and so I didn't have `grid` loaded.

The `sessionInfo()` after including `library(grid)` is

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] readr_1.3.1   metR_0.6.0    ggplot2_3.3.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.4        pillar_1.4.3      compiler_3.6.3    plyr_1.8.6        tools_3.6.3       digest_0.6.25     lubridate_1.7.4  
 [8] memoise_1.1.0     lifecycle_0.2.0   tibble_3.0.0      gtable_0.3.0      checkmate_2.0.0   pkgconfig_2.0.3   rlang_0.4.5      
[15] cli_2.0.2         rstudioapi_0.11   curl_4.3          withr_2.1.2       dplyr_0.8.5       stringr_1.4.0     vctrs_0.2.4      
[22] hms_0.5.3         tidyselect_1.0.0  glue_1.3.2        data.table_1.12.8 R6_2.4.1          fansi_0.4.1       purrr_0.3.3      
[29] farver_2.0.3      magrittr_1.5      backports_1.1.5   scales_1.1.0      ellipsis_0.3.0    assertthat_0.2.1  colorspace_1.4-1 
[36] labeling_0.3      stringi_1.4.6     munsell_0.5.0     crayon_1.3.4
```